# I want to show just the first video in the array by clicking a button with React.js

Tags: loops, reactjs, components

I am quite new with React.
So I have a button that when I click is changing between ShowMore and ShowLess but I would like to show just the first video of the array and show more if I press this button.
Can you please help me?
Here's the code:

```
class Videos extends Component {

state = {
  shouldHide: true
};

onClick = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 if (this.state.shouldHide) {
  this.setState({
    shouldHide: false
  });
} else {
  this.setState({
    shouldHide: true
  });
}
};

addVideo = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
this.props.showVideoModalAdd();
};

render = () => {
const { videos, allowEdit, specialistId } = this.props;
console.log(this.state);
const result = allowEdit || (videos && videos.length > 0) ? (
  <div>
    {videos.map(video => (
      <div key={video.id}>
        <Video
          video={video}
          allowEdit={allowEdit}
          specialistId={specialistId}
        />
      </div>
    ))}
    {allowEdit && (
      <span className="edit pull-right">
        <a href="#" onClick={this.addVideo}>+ Add Video</a>
        <br /><br />
        <a href="#" onClick={this.onClick}>
           {this.state.shouldHide ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More'}
        </a>
      </span>
    )}
  </div>
  ) : null;
  return result;
};
}
```

I know so far that I should change the videos.map but not sure how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways how you can achieve this. Essentially you want to check weather the state `shouldHide` and see if the `map` should continue or stop at the first iteration.

```
if (this.state.shouldHide && i > 0) {
  return false;
}
```

I would also encourage you to refactor your code a little, maybe put the `map` into its own method and use conditional blocks instead of conditional operators (`condition ? true : false`).

```js
const videos = [
  { id: 1, title: "first" },
  { id: 2, title: "second" },
  { id: 3, title: "third" }
];

class Videos extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { shouldHide: true };
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick() {
    this.setState({ shouldHide: !this.state.shouldHide });
  }

  addVideo(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Add video by callback.");
    // this.props.showVideoModalAdd();
  }

  render() {
    const { videos, allowEdit, specialistId } = this.props;
    console.log(this.state);
    const result = allowEdit || videos && videos.length > 0
      ? <div>
        {videos.map((video, i) => {
            if (this.state.shouldHide && i > 0) {
              return false;
            }
            return (
              <div key={video.id}>
                <div id="video">{video.title}</div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        {allowEdit && <span className="edit pull-right">
              <a href="#" onClick={this.addVideo}>+ Add Video</a>
              <br /><br />
              <a href="#" onClick={this.onClick}>
                {
                  this.state.shouldHide
                    ? "Show More"
                    : "Show Less"
                }
              </a>
            </span>}
      </div>
      : null;
    return result;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Videos videos={videos} allowEdit={true} specialistId={420} />,
  document.getElementById("View")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='View'></div>
```